# How to create two reports in same pdf using dompdf

Tags: php, pdf

I am doing a site for travel agency.it has a report creation module,reports are saved in pdf format i have used dompdf  for pdf creation .I need the same pdf should contain two reports .I got the two reports in same pdf but the `2nd one should starts in a new page`. how could i do this?

```
<?php
require_once("dompdf_config.inc.php");

$html =
  '<html><body>'.
  '<p>Put your html here, or generate it with your favourite '.
  'templating system.</p>'.
  '</body></html>';

$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("sample.pdf");

?>
```

I have used the above code but the $html variable used different.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
style="page-break-after:always"
```

to create new page.

//edit full snippet of code:

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;">Your 2 page</div>
```

Comment: You must create div which contains your second page:
<div style="page-break-after:always;">Your 2 page</div>

Answer (score 0):

Call `$dompdf->new_page()`;

Props for the Googling skills by the way.

Comment: v. G.I got an error message Call to undefined method DOMPDF::new_page(); i have used $var=$dompdf->get_canvas();
   $var->new_page('bonjour', '2');then a new page added at the end .But how i could i insert data to it.